# open WPF application on usb scanner scan

Tags: c#, wpf, usb, interceptor

I am trying to detect when the user scans a card on a USB card reader, which is basically a verry fast keyboar. Now when wpf application starts, it's on foreground and have a focus on certain textbox. So the easy part is complete.

Now on which things should I focus first when I am dealing with this kind of a problem?

Is it possible to create some kind of a usb port listener, that can open my wpf application and write the scanned string, if was activated from USB port1?

All I can help you with is the information from computer management. This usb scanner is displayed like keyboard and has this inforamiton:

```
Device HID\VID_13BA&PID_0018\6&265a4e67&1&0000 was configured.
Driver Name: keyboard.inf
Class Guid: {4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Driver Date: 06/21/2006
Driver Version: 10.0.10586.0
Driver Provider: Microsoft
Driver Section: HID_Keyboard_Inst.NT
Driver Rank: 0xFF1003
Matching Device Id: HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_KEYBOARD
Outranked Drivers: input.inf:HID_DEVICE:00FF1005
Device Updated: false
Parent Device: USB\VID_13BA&PID_0018\5&23ca3ecc&0&1
```

Regards!

Comment: If you use the scanner in it's "keyboard wedge" mode (it emulates a keyboard), you're going to have a heck of a time managing where the focus is (i.e. when you type where they keystrokes go). If it's in the wrong place, scanning something can end up doing a whole lot of "random" stuff, like banging randomly on your keyboard. It's usually best to reprogram the scanner to appear as a serial port or some other device, and specifically read from it. Then, you know what data came from the scanner, for sure.

Comment: Thank you, I have found an interceptor lib in c++ and I am using it, but just like u said I will have to know where is the cursor, so instead of that I am trying to bring my wpf application in the front of the screen. So I have created a new thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526144/bring-wpf-window-to-the-front-with-c-application

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what is happening is: you textbox in you app has only the visual focus, not the keyboard focus. So, when you scan, the text from scanner is not going to the textbox.

Assuming you have a TextBox1 control, in Loaded event in your app you should send the focus to TextBox1 this way:

```
TextBox1.Focus();
Keyboard.Focus(TextBox1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have posted a new thread, maybe you can here understand my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506118/opening-wpf-window-with-shellexecutea-and-make-it-active-so-that-you-can-direct